# I have error in a transformation saying Couldn't get row from result set and Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 2

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

```
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - ERROR (version 5.1.0.0, build 1 from 2014-06-19_19-02-57 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - Couldn't get row from result set
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - 
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 2
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - Value '7614399astanton0000-00-00 00:00:00scriptps2016-11-10 13:47:3600ûû12016-11-11 00:00:00  225.490000.00000    225.49000ûOPNû6228638ûEPP
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

This line is pretty clearly says:

```
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - 
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - Unable to get value 'Date' from database resultset, index 2
2016/11/14 09:18:07 - installment.0 - Value '7614399astanton0000-00-00 00:00:00scriptps2016-11-10 13:47:3600ûû12016-11-11 00:00:00  225.490000.00000    225.49000ûOPNû6228638ûEPP
```

That you have error converting (values in row starting from 0)

```
13:47:3600ûû12016-11-11 00:00:00
```

..to a Date value. You have to specify correct date conversion mask. Also characters like

```
ûû1
```

hint that most probably you have also incorrect encoding trouble.